# no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Name, Age, gender, salary, subject FROM Teachers

Tags: android, sqlite

my `fetch();` function

```
public Cursor fetch() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { databaseHelper.teacher_ID,databaseHelper.teacher_Name,databaseHelper.Age,databaseHelper.Gender,databaseHelper.Salary,databaseHelper.subject};
    Cursor cursor = database.query(databaseHelper.Table_Name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

my main where i call it

```
  final String [] from =new String[]{databaseHelper.teacher_ID,databaseHelper.teacher_Name,databaseHelper.Gender,databaseHelper.Age,databaseHelper.subject,databaseHelper.Salary
};

final int [] to =new int[]{R.id.id,R.id.name,R.id.age,R.id.gender,R.id.salary,R.id.subject};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    dbManger=new DBManger(this);
    dbManger.open();

    Cursor cursor= dbManger.fetch();
```

and here is my table

```
public final static String Table_Name="Teachers";

public static final String teacher_ID="_id";


public static final String teacher_Name="Name";


public static final String subject="subject";


public static final String Salary="salary";


public static final String Gender="gender";


public static final String Age="Age";
```

public  final static String DB_Name="School";

```
public  static final int Version=1;


private static final String Create_table="create table "+ Table_Name + "(" + teacher_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+ teacher_Name +" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ subject +" TEXT NOT NULL , "+
Salary +" INTEGER NOT NULL , "+Gender+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ Age+ " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that Create_table resolves to the string

```
create table Teachers(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    Name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    subject TEXT NOT NULL, 
    salary INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    gender TEXT NOT NULL, 
    Age INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Which is valid working SQL then the most likely reason why the column has not been found, is that the above SQL has not in fact been used.

One of the most common (if not the most common) reason is due to a misunderstanding about the **onCreate** method in the Database Helper (the class that is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper).

This **onCreate** only runs automatically when the database itself is created, which is once unless the database is deleted, in which case the **onCreate** method would run again.

So if changes are made to the structure of the databases (e.g. new columns are added) then this change will not be reflected unless the database is deleted

- If the onUpgrade method follows the typical drop the tables then call the **onCreate** method, this would also recreate the tables.

The fix to your issue is quite likely to be to do one of the following :-

- Delete/Clear the App's data from settings
- Uninstall the App

and then to rerun the App.